# How inject $stateProvider in angular application?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I try to use [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.com/), and try to inject $stateProvider:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test/appModule.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="appModule">
        <div ng-controller="appController">
            {{date}}
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js (test/appModule.js)**

```
var module = angular.module("appModule", ['ui.router']);

module.controller('appController', ['$scope', '$stateProvider',
    function ($scope, $stateProvider) {
        $scope.date = new Date();
    }]);
```

**stack trace**

```
Error: Unknown provider: $stateProviderProvider <- $stateProvider
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js:28:236
...
```

If I remove *$stateProvider* and *ui.router* with comments everything will work:

```
var module = angular.module("appModule"/*, ['ui.router']*/);
module.controller('appController', ['$scope'/*, '$stateProvider'*/,
    function ($scope, $stateProvider) {
        $scope.date = new Date();
    }]);
```

So the problem with injection *$stateProvider* any ideas about resolving?

**P.S.** I have tried [ui sample](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) it works, but I cannot figure out why mine does not.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When using it in a controller you have to use `$state`:

```
angular.module("appModule", ['ui.router']).controller('appController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
}]);
```

You can only use the state provider in the config, for example:

```
angular.module('appModule').config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    /* do w/e with state provider */
})];
```

Comment: Hi @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2204158/jon-snow , how about '$urlRouterProvider'? can I use that in the controller or that one should also be only used in the config? If that's the case what should I use instead? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @FarzanMajdani depends on what you want to do, you could describe your case in a new question. Otherwise `$urlRouterProvider` can only be used in the config, but you can inject `$urlRouter` into controllers. NOTE that `$urlRouter` doesn't have all the methods from `$urlRouterProvider`.

Comment: Thank you, wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out!

Comment: @JonSnow: My question is: why is it like that? And what part of the ui-router code makes this distinction between module config and e.g. controllers?

Comment: This isn't exclusively a ui-router thing, its how Angular modules operate in general. You have configuration that's only available before the app has been bootstrapped (in this case `$stateProvider` that you use to register states) and configuration that you can do afterwards. I'd imagine it would be a mess if you were allowed to register new routes after app has been bootstrapped. I think this question does a better job at explaining it than me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663019/angular-js-why-the-difference-between-module-config-injection-and-controller-in

Answer (score 0):

```
var bootstrapApp = angular.module('bootstrapDemoApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ui.router']);

bootstrapApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {




 // For any unmatched url, redirect to /
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

 // Now set up the states
 $stateProvider
  .state('login', {
   url: "/",
   controller: "loginCtrl",
   templateUrl: "partials/login.html"
 })
});
```