# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using  `$http.get`. All injections seems to be in place but I am getting error: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`.

**UPDATED**

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$state', '$http', function ($scope, $state, $http) {
        $scope.getEntryStateUrl = function(apiUrl){
            $http.get(apiUrl).success(function(data){/*...*/}));

    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for pointing out about `success` and injection. Now I am facing [this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310486/running-into-infinite-digest-cycle-while-binding-to-function-with-http-inside)

Comment: You have an injector mistake in your syntax. $scope is followed by $stateprovider in your function, but not your injector. You need to inject $stateProvider.

Answer (score 2):

You're injecting $state and trying to use $stateProvider as a parameter of the success callback? The success method of $http automaticly assigns the parameters of success:

> success(function(data, status, headers, config){});

So when you're doing this:

```
success(function(data, $stateProvider){});
```

You're assigning the status object returned by the $http call to variable $stateProvider. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Also you've got an extra parenthesis `)` at the end of your success method:

```
$http.get(apiUrl).success(function(data){/*...*/}));
```

Should be:

```
$http.get(apiUrl).success(function(data){/*...*/});
```

It would help if you actually mentioned in your question what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Check the variable names that you are declaring before the controller function. You are missing $stateProvider

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$state', '$http', function ($scope, $state, $http) {
```

Comment: Now I am getting `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProviderProvider <- $stateProvider`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931040/how-inject-stateprovider-in-angular-application

Comment: If you are not using that variable anywhere in your controller, simply remove both the string and the function argument called `$stateProvider`. If you do need it, make sure that you are referencing ui-router when you create your Angular module.

Comment: .. and thanks for your link. I overlooked the fact that your variable needs to be called $state instead of $stateProvider, updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function receives `inputUrl` but you pass `apiUrl` to `$http.get`